# How to pass values between C++20 Coroutines?

Tags: c++, yield, c++20, c++-coroutine

In C++20 the new Coroutines TS is being introduced.
This is the foundation to build coroutine-logic from.

There are some examples online of how one might build e.g. generators, tasks and other abstractions on top, such as https://github.com/Quuxplusone/coro/ and https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro

However, so far I've been unable to find any example of how passing a value *to* a partially-executed coroutine. This is rather common, as examples of coroutine usage in other languages show. A few examples:

- Python3 implementation of Conway's Game of Life using coroutines: [code](https://gist.github.com/ramalho/da5590bc38c973408839), [blogpost explanation](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Pythonorama/python_coroutines.shtml)
- [Ruby's yield implementation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Fiber.html#method-c-yield).
- [passing multiple values to a Boost.Coroutine](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.coroutine#ex.coroutine_03)

I have so far not been able to wrap my head around how this would work with the Coroutines TS, however. This is how far I got:

- When `co_yield expr` is called this is transformed into `co_await my_promise_type.yield_value(expr)`, which should return `std::suspend_always`.
- Later the coroutine is resumed by calling `resume()` on the handle, which will call `awaiter.await_resume()` whose return value will be the type of the whole `co_await` epression.

Is this correct? Is there something missing? How is the compiler able to figure out the types here? Are there any example implementations available of coroutine-types that currently implement this?

Comment: Perhaps read something about [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)

Comment: I am aware of continuation passing style as used in other languages (i.e. Haskell). CPS is a more fundamental abstraction which could be used to implement coroutines (but maybe more difficult for compilers to optimize?) . The Coroutine TS does not use CPS.

Comment: But you could  sometimes (with pain and care) code in C++ using CPS